# d3 bar chart implementation in teams viewApp with angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

need some help. Can't implement bar chart to team statistic(can't add it to wright place):

```
var team = [];
        team = teams.teams;
        for (var i = 0; i < team.length; i++) {
            var dataset = [];
            dataset = [team[i].spAchieved, team[i].spEstimated];
            // console.log(dataset);

            var w = 100;
            var h = 100;
            var barPadding = 1;

            var svg = d3.select("#chart")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

            svg.selectAll("rect")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", (d, i) => i * (w / dataset.length))
                .attr("y", d => h - d)
                .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
                .attr("height", d => d)
                .attr("fill", (d) => "rgb(100, 0, " + (d * 5) + ")");

            svg.selectAll("text")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("text")
                .text(d => d)
                .attr("x", (d, i) => i * (w / dataset.length) + 15)
                .attr("y", d => h - (d * 4) + 45);
        };
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center" *ngIf="user">
<h1>TEAM View</h1>

<div class="layer1">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/profile']">{{user.name}}</a>
</div>
<div class="layer2">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/addteam']">Add New Team</a>
</div>

<div id="chart">
<ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let newTeam of teams;">
    <div *ngFor="let team of newTeam;">
        <li class="list-group-item">Team Name: {{team.teamName}}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Sprint Number: {{team.sprintNumber}}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Completed At: {{team.completedAt}}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Completed: {{team.completed}}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">SP Achieved: {{team.spAchieved}}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">SP Estimated: {{team.spEstimated}}</li>
        <svg class="chart" #chart></svg>
        <br/><br/>
    </div>
</ul>
</div>
```

So for now, its shows the all chart in `div`, and if change from `id` to `body` its shown on the bottom, if to `li`, then in the header, and i can't implement it to `spAchieved` and `spEstimated`. Thank you

Make some changes and now it execute correctly in debuger, but don't save graphs at the end of execution.

Now code looks like this:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

import * as d3 from "d3-selection";   //

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard',
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit {
    user: Object;
    teams: any;
    //teamName: Object;

constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
) { }

ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
        this.user = profile.user;
    },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
            return false;
        });

    this.authService.getAllTeams().subscribe(teams => {
        // console.log(teams);
        this.teams = Object.keys(teams).map(key => teams[key]);
        // console.log(this.teams);
    },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
            return false;
        });
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    //Called after ngAfterContentInit when the component's view has been initialized. Applies to components only.
    //Add 'implements AfterViewInit' to the class.

    this.authService.getAllTeams().subscribe(teams => {
        // console.log(teams);
        this.teams = Object.keys(teams).map(key => teams[key]);
        // console.log(this.teams);

        const canvas = () => {
            this.teams = Object.keys(teams).map(key => teams[key]);
            var team = [];
            team = teams.teams;

            for (var i = 0; i < team.length; i++) {
                var dataset = [];
                dataset = [team[i].spAchieved, team[i].spEstimated];
                // dataset = 
                // console.log(dataset);

                var w = 100;
                var h = 100;
                var barPadding = 1;

                var j = 0;
                // var svg = d3.select("#chart .list-element:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")")
                // var svg = d3.select("li")
                // console.log("#chart .list-element:nth-child(" + (i +1) +") .graph");
                    var svg = d3.select("#chart .list-element:nth-child(" + (i+1) +") .graph")     
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);

                svg.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(dataset)
                    .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("x", (d, i) => i * (w / dataset.length))
                    .attr("y", d => h - d)
                    .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
                    .attr("height", d => d)
                    .attr("fill", (d) => "rgb(100, 0, " + (d * 5) + ")");

                svg.selectAll("text")
                    .data(dataset)
                    .enter()
                    .append("text")
                    .text(d => d)
                    .attr("x", (d, i) => i * (w / dataset.length) + 15)
                    .attr("y", d => h - d);
            };
        }
        canvas();
    },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
            return false;
        });
}
```

}

And HTML

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center" *ngIf="user">
    <h1>TEAM View</h1>

    <div class="layer1">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/profile']">{{user.name}}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="layer2">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/addteam']">Add New Team</a>
    </div>

    <div id="chart">
        <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let newTeam of teams;">
            <div class="list-element" *ngFor="let team of newTeam;">
                <li class="list-group-item">Team Name: {{team.teamName}}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Sprint Number: {{team.sprintNumber}}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Completed At: {{team.completedAt}}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Completed: {{team.completed}}</li>
                <!-- <li class="list-group-item">SP Achieved: {{team.spAchieved}}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">SP Estimated: {{team.spEstimated}}</li> -->
                <!-- <svg width="100" height="100" class="chart" #chart></svg> -->
                <div class="graph">

                </div>
                <br/><br/>
            </div>
        </ul>
        <!--  -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem, for now, was in execution d3 code befor rest, so i changed ngOnInit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i thought that something rewrite the page in the end of execution, and i found what. Now code looks like this(i erase the function `canvas` and reassignment `this.teams`):

```
    import { Component, AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

import * as d3 from "d3-selection";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard',
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})

export class DashboardComponent implements AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit {
    user: Object;
    teams: any;

constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
) { }

ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
        this.user = profile.user;
    },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
            return false;
        });

    this.authService.getAllTeams().subscribe(teams => {
        // console.log(teams);
        this.teams = Object.keys(teams).map(key => teams[key]);
        // console.log(this.teams);
    },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
            return false;
        });
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.authService.getAllTeams().subscribe(teams => {
        // console.log(this.teams);
        var team = [];
        team = this.teams[0];

        for (var i = 0; i < team.length; i++) {
            var dataset = [];
            dataset = [team[i].spAchieved, team[i].spEstimated];
            // console.log(dataset);

            var w = 100;
            var h = 100;
            var barPadding = 1;

            var svg = d3.select("#chart .list-element:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ") .graph")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

            svg.selectAll("rect")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", (d, i) => i * (w / dataset.length))
                .attr("y", d => h - d)
                .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
                .attr("height", d => d)
                .attr("fill", (d) => "rgb(100, 0, " + (d * 5) + ")");

            svg.selectAll("text")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("text")
                .text(d => d)
                .attr("x", (d, i) => i * (w / dataset.length) + 15)
                .attr("y", d => h - d);
        };
    },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
            return false;
        });
}
```

}

Now its works fine. Maybe it help someone. Thank you.